# Could not compare a value in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

What is wrong with the below syntax:

```
    @ECHO OFF

SET FLAG=TRUE

invalidcmd
call :checkERR "Duplicate Entry " 
@ECHO %FLAG%
IF "%FLAG%" EQU  "TRUE"(
    @ECHO DONEXT
) 
ELSE (
@ECHO INVALID

)

:checkerr
    REM echo %ERRORLEVEL% with %1
    IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        @ECHO %1
        SET FLAG=FALSE
        REM EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
        )
```

Objective is if the `%FLAG%` is `FALSE` then it must echo `INVALID`.

But I am getting the below output:

```
D:\ >installer.bat [hidden arguments]
'invalidcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
"Duplicate Entry "
FALSE
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: Late comment, but I don't think you are using `DOS`, the OS fro the 80s/90s. I think you mean `CMD`, `Command Prompt`/ `Command Processor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There must be a separator before the opening parenthesis of the `IF` true-condition target
2. That opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`
3. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a separator and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line
4. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line

ie

```
if condition (
 something
) else (
 someotherthing
)
```